# Determining the parent of a UIElementCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reflection

I'd like to know if there is any way to determine whether the Parent of a UIElementCollection is of Type Grid or not, preferably with reflection.

UIElementCollection is a WPF object, used for Children from a Grid for example.
Class definition:

```
public class UIElementCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Grid class definition:

```
public class Grid : Panel, IAddChild
```

Panel class definition:

```
public abstract class Panel : FrameworkElement, IAddChild
{
    public UIElementCollection Children { get; }
    // Bunch of other members...
}
```

**EDIT:**
Current devious code:

```
        string visualParent = "";
        if (collection.Count == 0)
        {
            collection.Add(element);
            visualParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(collection[0]).ToString();
            collection.Remove(element);
        }
        else
        {
            visualParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(collection[0]).ToString();
        }

        if (!visualParent.Contains("Grid"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The UIElementCollection's Parent is not a Grid. Please provide a Grid.Children UIElementCollection.");
        }
```

Comment: You mean in a method where you only have a reference to the `UIElementCollection` and not the `Panel` object?

Comment: Given that the collection contains at least one FrameworkElement, you may query its `Parent` property.

Comment: have you looked into the visualtreehelper?

Comment: Apologies, the question was incomplete. No, you do not have access to anything else beside the UIElementCollection. And the UIElementCollection might be empty, therefore I've got a very devious solution right now, which is checking if the collection is empty, if so add one item and then get the Parent using the VisualTreeHelper. But I want to get rid of all these if statements, and potentionally having to add an item just to get the Parent.

Comment: How are you getting the reference to the collection, and why is it important to detect whether the parent is a Grid (what are you ultimately trying to do)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection isn't necessary here. You can clean this code up some by using [the is operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx), which can detect valid downcasts, such as from DependencyObject to Grid. You can eliminate some if statements by using a UIElement dedicated to this parent detection operation (meaning an element never used for anything else). Consider:

```
var idx = collection.Add(parentDetectionElement);
var isGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(collection[idx]) is Grid;
collection.RemoveAt(idx);
if(!isGrid)
{ 
    throw new ArgumentException("The UIElementCollection's Parent is not a Grid. Please provide a Grid.Children UIElementCollection.");
}
```

This is much cleaner and avoids messy and potentially buggy string operations, and it no longer depends on inspecting the collection. However, it's important that you use a dedicated element instance for doing this, in order to guarantee that it won't already be in the collection's size. If you encapsulate this within a function, then you can declare a new UIElement locally and ensure this. Additionally, encapsulation improves your control flow options; if you want, you can return a boolean indicating whether the parent is a Grid, rather than throwing an exception.

If you're set on using reflection, then you can inspect the inaccessible property which holds the visual parent's reference. According to [the UIElementCollection source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/UIElementCollection.cs,213f995f9cd0d160), it's VisualParent which is of type UIElement. Once you've found it, you can inspect the type as shown above. Notice that the access modifier of VisualParent is internal and the class opens the MS.Internal namespace. This is why the CLR can detect the parent type: they have expressly designed the class to permit Microsoft code functionality forbidden to general consumers.

Comment: Thank you for your post. This solution still potentionally requires to add an element to the collection. I'm also trying to avoid that. I'm familiar with the is operator, this is just very old code I'm cleaning up.

Comment: Unless you can structure your program such that you can guarantee the collection is never empty when you call this code, you'll have to add an element to detect the parent control to handle the empty case, because UIElementCollection isn't itself part of the visual tree, so it doesn't have a parent. Alternatively, where is this collection coming from? If you can add code that shows how you get the reference, it might be possible to do a determination there.

Comment: Considering the fact that UIElementCollection is not part of the visual tree and therefore doesn't have a parent, I will go with the solution you provided. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I see; that wasn't mentioned in your question. I've made an update showing what you can look at with reflection to get the VP reference.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Reflection would be more concise and clean, however it's been made internal for a reason, as you stated above. I'll stick to this solution as it appears more appropriate. Thanks again for your effort.